# Get value of a specific modifier?

Tags: expresso-store

I am building a gift certificate item and am using gift voucher options as modifiers.

It all works great.  However, I need to output those modifier values into a template in a particular design – as such, I want to get values of particular modifiers.

For example, I have a modifier, system called this  ‘modifiers_6’ - I can only get its value when I use the modifiers loop – but I also get all other modifiers.

Was hoping is could be like {modifiers_6:modifier_value} - I wrapped the modifiers and items loop tags around this but no luck.

Any ideas? How do I target specific modifiers without using the whole loop?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to run a conditional check on the modifier names along the lines of:

```
{modifier_options}

// Only output a particular modifier by name
{if option_name == 'my_name'} 
    {option_name} {if price_mod_val} ({price_mod}) {/if}
{/if}

{/modifier_options}
```

Then you limit the output to a particular modifier. You still need to wrap it in the `{modifier_options}` loop but you can just wrap the whole section in this if you need to.